# How to solve TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined error after replacing lodash find function with native JS filter function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove lodash find function, so my change is basically replacing this line:

```js
const current = find(items, elem => elem.id === item.id);
```

with this one:

```js
const current = items ? items.filter(function(x) {
  return x.id === item.id;
}) : null;
```

But I'm getting this error:

> app.js:659 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: `console.log(items)` what are you getting back for a result here? It's obviously not what you expect.

Comment: items
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1406, title: Array(2), description: Array(2), detailExplanation: Array(2), damage: 0, …}
1: {id: 1407, title: Array(2), description: Array(2), detailExplanation: Array(2), damage: 0, …}
2: {id: 1408, title: Array(2), description: Array(2), detailExplanation: Array(2), damage: 0, …}
3: {id: 1409, title: Array(2), description: Array(2), detailExplanation: Array(2), damage: 30, …}
4: {id: 1410, title: Array(2), description: Array(2), detailExplanation: Array(2), damage: 0, …}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: with the ternary there it is not possible for the interpreter to attempt to call `filter` on `items` while it's undefined. are you sure this is in line 659?

Comment: yes i am sure, and i did the check to avoid calling filter on an undefined. But when i console.log item, the output is in the comment above. that's why i can't understand what is wrong

Comment: Is the first find with lodash working ?

Comment: note that `find` returns *one* item while `filter` returns *an array* of matches. my guess is that you're not accounting for this change. consider using `items.find()` instead to get one item

Comment: Yes. the lodash function is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why filter is not working but this line solved the problem

```
    const current         = items.find(x => x.id === item.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method returns an array. If you want to use that method, you will have to select the first element of the returned array in order to have the same behaviour that lodash `find` method has:

```
const current = items.filter(x => x.id === item.id)[0];
```

That being said, it is simpler to use the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method of array:

```
const current = items.find(x => x.id === item.id);
```

If you opt for this second option, have in mind that `find` is not supported in Internet Explorer.